# How does leaflet determine teh position of bound markers, and can I change this w/o using anchor for each feature?

Tags: leaflet

PLease see this jsfiddle (scroll down in the JS window to below the geoJSON)

https://jsfiddle.net/n3zerj2q/1/

```
var prevLayer = null;

var map = L.map("map").setView([30, 0], 3);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var noStyle = {
   fillColor: "#fff",
   weight: 1,
   opacity: 1,
   color: 'red',
   dashArray: '3',
   fillOpacity: 0
};

var myGeojSonLayerGroup = L.geoJson(world, {
  onEachFeature: onEachFeature2
}).addTo(map);


function onEachFeature2(feature, layer) {
  if (feature.properties && feature.properties.name) {
     layer.bindPopup('<span class="pcA">' + feature.properties.name + '</span>')
  }
  layer.setStyle(noStyle);

  layer.on({
     mouseover: function (e) {
        e.target.openPopup();
        if (prevLayer !== null) {
           // Reset style
           prevLayer.setStyle(styleA());
        }
        var thisLayer = e.target;
        thisLayer.setStyle(styleX())
        prevLayer = thisLayer;
     }
  });

}

function styleA() {
  return {
     fillColor: "#fff", fillOpacity: 0.0
  };
}
function styleX() {
  return {
     fillColor: "pink", fillOpacity: 0.4
  };
}
```

It simply displays a world map and as the user rolls over country a popup appears with the country name (as well as some color styling) - mostly this is positioned "sensibly" more or less in the middle of the country, but for some (esp bigger ones) it's way off - eg the USA, China, Russia, Argentina...

I'm not setting the position of these - leaflet is, somehow... Other than editing the (large) geoJSON to include anchor points for each country, I wonder if there's some way of tweaking whatever leaflet is doing? Why, for example, does it place Antarctica's where it does? Or China's? etc....

Comment: You're asking two questions in one: (1) how are the default popup/tooltip positions calculated (polygon centroid) and (2) how to manually specify the position of a bound popup (explicitly instantiate a popup). Please edit this so you're making **one** question.

Comment: I'm not asking how to manually specify the position of a bound marker - I know how to do this. I want to know how Leaflet does it so I can understand why some are so out of where I would expect them to be, and maybe do something about that. I specifically don't want to have to set the position for each marker myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when a `Popup` is about to be shown, it will check where, in [this specific bit of code](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/fd202ce5b618fd23f998fff79c865b1baedbd41d/src/layer/DivOverlay.js#L252-L261):

```
    if (!latlng) {
        if (source.getCenter) {
            latlng = source.getCenter();
        } else if (source.getLatLng) {
            latlng = source.getLatLng();
        } else if (source.getBounds) {
            latlng = source.getBounds().getCenter();
        } else {
            throw new Error('Unable to get source layer LatLng.');
        }
    }
```

So for popups without an explicit `latlng`, the position will dpend on themethods available on the source layer - this means that for `Rectangle`s and `ImageOverlay`s that'll run `getBounds().getCenter()`, for `Marker`s and `Circle`s that'll run `getLatLng()`, and for `Polyline`s and `Polygon`s that'll run `getCenter()`.

The `getCenter()` method from `Polygon` just [delegates the work elsewhere](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/fd202ce5b618fd23f998fff79c865b1baedbd41d/src/layer/vector/Polygon.js#L71):

```
    return PolyUtil.polygonCenter(this._defaultShape(), this._map.options.crs);
```

...and, finally, the `polygonCenter()` function [will calculate the polygon's centroid](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/fd202ce5b618fd23f998fff79c865b1baedbd41d/src/geometry/PolyUtil.js#L58).

Note that the [implementation](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/fd202ce5b618fd23f998fff79c865b1baedbd41d/src/geometry/PolyUtil.js#L68) only takes into account the first ring of the polygon:

```
if (!LineUtil.isFlat(latlngs)) {
    console.warn('latlngs are not flat! Only the first ring will be used');
    latlngs = latlngs[0];
}
```

This is due to the centroid algorithm only being able to handle "simple" polygons, with just an outer ring. Remember to read the [OGC SFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Features) specification for a refresher on (multi)polygon rings.

Comment: Thanks for this - very interesting. It's kind of intriguing as to just why Russia, China, USA, Argetina, Chile and Australia (in particular) are so far out when all the others are pretty good. Still, "correcting" the source code is way above my pay-grade :) so in my case I just use a switch-case block to catch that handful of countries, and set the marker offsets manually - the offsets depends on the zoom level,  but simple enough to work out.